# Adding content type fields to a display form

Tags: display-form

I have created a custom Display form for a content type. On the display form I want to add few fields of the content type. How to do that?

Comment: First you write you created it, how?

Comment: Can you clarify what version of SharePoint you are using and how you created a custom Display form? i.e. did you use Infopath, customise DispForm.aspx through SharePoint Designer etc?